# Function which outputs a list of factors

Tags: list, haskell

For an assignment I need to create a function which takes a list of `Int`s and outputs all of a number's factors in a new list. Thing is, I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I know its signature needs to be like this though :

```
factors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
factors xs = ???
```

So when you take a list like this : `[2,5,7,8]`

It outputs `[[],[],[],[2,4]]`

I have tried things with map, filter, mod, list comprehension or higher order functions, but since this is the first language I am learning, it's very hard for me to come up with any sort of solution.

Comment: The first step is to have a function that does this for a single input (i.e. `Int -> [Int]`). You can then use this function for each element of your list-type input (for example by `map`ping over that input).

Comment: yeah i figured as much, but since i am not allowed to use local scopes i cant just create a new variable through let or where.Thats the problem i am having atm.

Comment: So define a new function elsewhere, without `let` or `where`. Use the global scope instead of the local one.

Comment: I think before looking for a Haskell approach, how would you do that algorithmically?

Answer (score 3):

So the first thing to do if we get stuck is to skip the programming part of the problem and start by solving the actual problem. We want to take 1 number, get the factors of that number, wrap the factors inside a list, and keep going until there are no more numbers to factor.

So how do we get the factors of a number? A number x is a factor of y if we can write y as a product of x and some other integer z. Therefor, 2 is a factor of 8 because 8 can be written as 2*4.

Using this information we also know that 8 must be divisble by 2 without rest, which it is. Great! So know we know that for any two integers x and y, if x is divisible by y without rest, y is a factor.

Lets go to haskell and try some approach with the information : " x is a factor of y if y is divided by x with no rest"

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors y = [ x | x <- [1..y], y `mod` x == 0]
```

So, using a listcomp we can wrap all x:es from [1..y] and put them in a list, but **if and only if**

`y 'mod' that specific x equals 0`.

If we have a function to create a list with all the factors of one number, what if we just map that function to a list of numbers, and wrap the resulting lists in a new list, and return that list

```
listFactors :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
listFactors xs = map factors xs
```

If we do not want to show the multiplication identity 1 or the number itself we can just change the interval to [2..y-1]

Comment: And if you want to slightly increase the efficiency of the algorithm you could further change the interval to 2..y/2 as no factor will be larger than that.